# How to change a variable in multiple closures and use result

Tags: swift, closures

I'm uploading 3 different files to an AWS S3 Bucket. I'm checking if each upload is successful by returning a Bool. If all 3 uploads are successful then another part of my code will run.

The problem I'm having is the uploadSuccessful var is being changed within a closure so the rest of my code is running before it updates.

My code is as follows:

Upload function-

```
    func uploadData(fileUrl: URL, key: String, content: String, completion: @escaping(Bool) -> ()) {

    var success = false

    let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()
    expression.progressBlock = {(task, progress) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            // Do something e.g. Update a progress bar.
        })
    }

    let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()

        transferUtility.uploadFile(fileUrl, bucket: "liopa-datacapture-ios", key: key, contentType: content, expression: expression) { (task, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                success = false
                completion(success)
                return
            }

            print("Successfully uploaded")
            success = true
            completion(success)   
      }

}
```

Files to be uploaded-

```
var videoSuccessful = false
var audioSuccessful = false 
var landmarksSuccessful = false 


// upload files to S3 bucket
        // video file
        s3Bucket.uploadData(fileUrl: videoRecorder.outputFileLocation!, key: "ios-videos/\(userName)-\(device)/session-\(sessionNumber)-\(sessionTimestamp)/video-\(phraseNumber)/video-\(phraseNumber).mp4", content: "video") { (success) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                videoSuccessful = success
            }
        }
        // audio file
        s3Bucket.uploadData(fileUrl: audioRecorder.outputAudioLocation, key: "ios-videos/\(userName)-\(device)/session-\(sessionNumber)-\(sessionTimestamp)/video-\(phraseNumber)/audio-\(phraseNumber).flac", content: "audio") { (success) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                audioSuccessful = success
            }
        }
        //facial landmark coordinates
        s3Bucket.uploadData(fileUrl: createFacialLandmarksFile(), key: "ios-videos/\(userName)-\(device)/session-\(sessionNumber)-\(sessionTimestamp)/video-\(phraseNumber)/metadata/Phrase\(phraseNumber)-landmarks.txt", content: "text") { (success) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                landmarksSuccessful = success
            }
        }

        print(uploadSuccessful)

        if videoSuccessful && audioSuccessful && landmarksSuccessful  { // continue on
```

I know I'm probably going about this completely the wrong way. But how can I change the uploadSuccessful Bool straight away and then use it's value in the if statement at the end of the code?

Comment: Use a dispatch_group with enter/leave/notify. Also, in your current code if the last one succeed but not another one, you'll think it's successful. In addition, in your current code you are treating the request as they were sync, but they are asynchrone.

Comment: what is your requirement ? If any of the 3 task complete you consider it as successful ?

Comment: I'll have to look into dispatch_ group I've never heard of that. I'm still new to swift as you can see! And yes my logic wasn't too good on that one. I'll change it.

Comment: Yes @vivekDas I realise that. Was focusing more on changing the variable and didn't see what I'd done. I've edited my question.

Comment: Do the upload task in a background queue and use sync dispatch. that is the right way. If you do upload task in main queue your UI will get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a few points:

Your upload is asynchrone. Meaning that you should reach `print(uploadSuccessful)` before you do `uploadSuccessful = success`. 
To wait for all the asynchrone call to end before doing something else, use a `DispatchGroup`.
Even with that you may have issue because if the two fails but not the last one, you'll have `uploadSuccessful == true`.
You could use `let allRequestSucceed = true`
In the closure of each request, update `allRequestSucceed` ONLY if `success == false`, but a counter is a good way too.

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
let successFullRequestCounter: Int = 0

//First upload
group.enter()
s3Bucket.uploadData(fileUrl: ...) { (success) in
    if success { 
        successFullRequestCounter = successFullRequestCounter + 1
    }
    group.leave()
}

//Second upload
group.enter()
s3Bucket.uploadData(fileUrl: ...) { (success) in
    if success { 
        successFullRequestCounter = successFullRequestCounter + 1
    }
    group.leave()
}

//Third upload
group.enter()
s3Bucket.uploadData(fileUrl: ...) { (success) in
    if success { 
        successFullRequestCounter = successFullRequestCounter + 1
    }
    group.leave()
}

//Because of the enter()/leave(), this code will executes only when 3 uploaded ended
group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
    if successFullRequestCounter == 3 { 
        //All request did succeed
    }
    successFullRequestCounter = 0 //Reset the value if it's a instance var
}
```

Comment: I've tried using your example by implementing a counter and using DispatchGroup but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong. I can edit it into my original question.

Comment: This code should work, could you edit your question by appending your current version of code?

Comment: The `print(successCounter)` will always be at 0. I'd suggest to do `self.successCounter = 0` in any case, not only if it's equals to 3. Because if you try, then fail, it may be equals to 2, then retry again, you didn't reset it.

Comment: All I can say is I'm really sorry. I'm an actual idiot and have put the successCount = 1 in wrong place. I think i need to take a break. Your answer has worked. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I edited a few things checks. It should be better that way.